# Decompiling CHM (help) files with C or c++

Tags: c, chm, decompiler

I want to decompile CHM file to HTML format . Is it possible using c or c++ ? Is there any c or c++ library to do this.

Comment: I want to do this in windows and Linux platform

Comment: There is a compiler/decompiler for Windows, but it's a standalone executable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms669985 You could try to write your own decompiler by studying the CHM files you feed it and the HTML it produces (or if you just care about the result, run it from inside your program)

Comment: You can also use 7zip http://www.7-zip.org/ to extract all html files from *.chm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [CHMlib](http://www.jedrea.com/chmlib/), which has the [libCHMxx](http://www.mare.ee/indrek/libchmxx/) binding for C++ ; it seems it could run both on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible using C++. If you use Windows, you can do it using COM. An example you can find [here](http://code.entersources.com/f/Decompiling-CHM--help--files-with-C-_2_2497_0.aspx). This article is about C#, but it is done using COM interfaces and you can easily do the same in C++.

Answer (score 4):

The open source 7-zip file manager can browse and extract content from a .chm file.  Right-click and select Open Inside.  Download [is here.](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)